# I got 'Too many re-renders' while converting my axios codes to react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

It seems like react-query is a quiet popular so, I trying to add react-query to my exist codes.

the code below is the exist codes. it uses hooks (useEffect & useState), axios and returns response data.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { apiProvider } from 'services/modules/provider';
import { useLoading } from 'components/Loading/Loading';


export const useCommonApi = (url: string, params?: any) => {
 
   const [_, setLoading] = useLoading();
   const [State, setState] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const getState = async () => {
        const result: any = await apiProvider.get('common/' + url, params);
        let resultData = result.data || [];

        if (url === 'available_countries') {
          resultData = resultData.map((o: any) => {
            return { value: o.id, label: o.name };
          });
        }
  
        setState([...resultData]);
        return resultData;
      };

      getState();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, []);

  return State;
};
```

Here is the my new codes for react-query. I am trying to convert code above into react-query as below.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { apiProvider } from 'services/modules/provider';

import { useLoading } from 'components/Loading/Loading';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';



export const useCommonApi_adv = (url: string, params?: any) => {
  
  const [_, setLoading] = useLoading();
  const [State, setState] = useState<any>();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('fetchCommon', () => 
    axios('/api/v1/admin/common/' + url).then( (res) :any => {
        return res.data
    })
  )

  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'


    let resultData = data.data || [];
    if (url === 'available_countries') {
      resultData = resultData.map((o: any) => {
        return { value: o.id, label: o.name };
      });
    }

    setState([...resultData]);

  return State;
};
```

the my new codes(react-query) prints "too many render" when it is executed.
What did I wrong with it? any help please

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your state update function `setState` outside of an `useEffect`. This will run on the first render, update the state, which in turn triggers a rerender, update the state again and you end up in an endless loop. You probably want to wrap that logic into `useEffect` and only run it if `data` changes.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { apiProvider } from 'services/modules/provider';

import { useLoading } from 'components/Loading/Loading';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

export const useCommonApi_adv = (url: string, params?: any) => {
  
  const [_, setLoading] = useLoading();
  const [State, setState] = useState<any>();
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('fetchCommon', () => 
    axios('/api/v1/admin/common/' + url).then( (res) :any => {
        return res.data
    })
  )
 
  useEffect(() => {
    let resultData = data.data || [];
    if (url === 'available_countries') {
      resultData = resultData.map((o: any) => {
        return { value: o.id, label: o.name };
      });
    }

    setState([...resultData]);
  }, [data])


  if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'

  return State;
};
```

Comment: the answer is generally correct, but with react-query, there is no need to take the result `data`  of react-query and put it into local state.

Comment: That's true. The cleanest solution would probably be the usage of useQuery's `select` property.